# IPTables Firewall/Router/Gateway needing to block outbound traffic from users

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have multiple ethX interfaces.

- `eth0` is connected to the internet.
- `eth1` is connected to a trusted network.
- `eth2` is connected to a network I need to impose usage rules.

What I'd like to do is separate `eth1` and `eth2` into their own chains (trusted/untrusted) simply to maintain "easy on the eyes" rules.

```
:INPUT DROP
-A INPUT ! -i eth0 -j ACCEPT    # allows INPUT on traffic not internet based
... # More rules for eth0 allowing PING and shunting most everything else
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j trusted
-A INPUT -i eth2 -j untrusted
```

OUTPUT and FORWARD are currently set to ACCEPT due to the problems.

For the time being, `eth1` is just jumping to chain masquerade which is perfectly fine for the moment, but the confusion lies as to how to manipulate `eth2` as it hasn't panned out too well with my attempts.

My guess was to list all of the ALLOWED ports/protocols, but so far it's not working as devices connected through `eth2` cannot reach anything, not even the firewall server's DNS/DHCP.

```
:untrusted
-A untrusted -i eth2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

What I need is basically a set of rules which "say" the following:

1. If outgoing internet traffic on `eth0` is not PING, DROP
2. If `eth1` goes out to internet (`eth0`), accept it
3. If `eth2` goes out to internet on TCP port 80, accept it, drop everything else.
4. To GO out to internet, use masquerade through `eth0`

Any thoughts/suggestions would be truly appreciated!

Comment: @jasonwryan: Thanks for the edit!  I'm running on a kiosk with Fox21 and I don't have much option to format nicely/cleanly save for **bold** and have to use HTML breaks just to implement line feeds.

Comment: Wow: that is dedication! :)

Comment: LOL - no, not dedication...  it's a custom kernel/init where I simply haven't updated the repository in quite some time! :)  HOWEVER, I just tinkered with block quotes and the likes and believe I have things down-pat manually (ie: 4 spaces after an empty line starts a code block, etc.)

Comment: `-A INPUT ! eth0 -j ACCEPT`, isn't that missing a `-i` before the `eth0`? Apart from that: `untrusted` is already just for traffic coming in from `eth2`, so the `-A untrusted -i eth0 ...` makes no sense.

Comment: @wurtel Sorry, you are correct, the "-i" is missing (a typo HERE on my part since I couldn't copy/paste at the time.)  Regarding `-A untrusted` as the default policy is to DROP, the additional rules were intended for ACCEPT (thus ports not listed would drop) however I believe I typed in eth0 instead of eth2 where technically neither are "required" as I could have left the `-i ethX` out completely.

Comment: The `-i eth0` in the untrusted chain basically makes the rule a no-op. That's different from not being required... with `eth2` there it just incurs extra processing overhead (checking interface twice).

Answer (score 0):

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type ping -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP

-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

*nat
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Change the `192.168.2.0/24` to the network on `eth2` in the last line; that's so that just packets originating on the `eth2` network will be masqueraded.

I also prefer to explicitly add a rule to drop packets at the end of a chain instead of relying on the policy.

This should cover the points in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the post and for not saying "are you stupid?" with my 3am less than half-awake request #1 ("output of PING" instead of input) :)  I must have done something wrong with routing or the likes...  save for the network being used in your masquerade (I just used the interface) and the explicit drops, my logic was the same as yours.  (Another reason I wanted to divide this into separate chains.)  If `eth1` and `eth2` were on the same subnet in the example above, would that pose any foreseen issues?  (10.x.x.x)

Comment: Thank you again.  For what ever reason this particular layout isn't working out well and I can't find anything erroneous.  eth2 is connected to the WAN side of a wireless router.  With the firewall in place, the router calls the server's DHCP (and gets through) but for what ever reason the response acts as though it never makes it back to the router.  The server shows ongoing request/response broadcasts but the router just keeps requesting.  When I plug both in using a switch, it goes through perfectly.  Any thoughts?  (UDP 67-69 are open)

Comment: If `eth1` and `eth2` are on the same subnet, then routing towards that subnet will probably be wrong for one of the devices... never a good idea. Why not just connect one of the LAN ports of the wireless router to `eth2` and use it as an access point... I'm not a fan of double NAT.

Comment: I'm not a fan, either, and that's what I've had to do in the past.  The routers require WAN side for things as simple as NTP...  (D-Link and Tenda both seem to have a lease quirk in this regard).  At the moment I'm forced to do this (AP instead of router) as the routers are seemingly dropping the reply broadcast from DHCP - nothing in logs from either end showing anything out of the ordinary.  The local network is 10.x.x.x and the routers (their own lan side) are 192.168.x.1.  Now the ODD part is when plugging the router (WAN) into a managed switch...  the process goes through fine.

Comment: No chance of putting openwrt on the router? Seems like that would be the best solution, firewall it at the source.

Comment: wrt has two models listed for Tenda...  sadly they're not mine.  I haven't researched any further than that in case there's a way to install a boot-strap and go from there experimentally, but I know from experience the firmware upload is finicky as can be; even with factory images.